# Topology Questions Please!!!

Tags: general-topology

1. Which of the following are (i) U-neighborhoods of 1, (ii) H-neighborhoods of 1: 
   U is the usual topology and H is half-open interval topology ([a,b))

(a) [0,1] No and no

(b) [0,2] no and yes

(c) [0,1) no and yes

(d) [1,2) no and yes

(e) {1,2} no and no

(f) (0,1] yes and no

(These are the ones im really am not sure about because I have no idea how to do them).

1. Let X = {a,b,c,d} and T = {X,Ø,{a},{b,c},{a,b,c}}. List all T-neighborhoods of

   (a) the element of a

   - Because {a} is open, any subset of X will do, so they are all the subsets that contain a. These are {a}, {a,b}, {a,c}, {a,d}, {a,b,c}, {a,b,d}, {a,c,d}, {a,b,c,d}. (I think thats all of them).

   (b) the element of b

   - These would be {b,c}, {a,b,c}, {b,c,d}, and X.

Comment: Too many questions in one post. Please do ask only one or at most two things, otherwise the post's too long.

Comment: I removed some of the questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(a) is correct.

(b) is incorrect: $(0,2)$ is a $U$-open set containing $1$ and contained in $[0,2]$, so $[0,2]$ **is** a $U$-nbhd of $1$.

(c) is incorrect: $[0,1)$ doesn’t even contain $1$, so it can’t be a nbhd of $1$ in any topology.

(d) and (e) are correct.

(f) is incorrect: $(0,1]$ is not a nbhd of $1$ in either topology.

For the second question, your answers are correct.

Comment: Def of a neighborhood is a subset N of X for which there is an open set U such that x belongs to U which is a subset of N.

Comment: @Yesmmmmm: In that case your answers to the second question are correct, and your answer to (b) of the first question is not, since $1\in(0,2)\subseteq[0,2]$. I’ve modified my answer to match the definition that you’re using.

Comment: @Yesmmmmm: You’re very welcome.